# ASP.NET MVC Html.SubmitImage

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am looking for Html.SubmitImage in RC1 and don't see it anywhere when reflecting through the MVC assemblies.

Has it been moved / removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SubmitImage has moved to MvcFutures in RC1.  You can find the actual source at http://www.codeplex.com/aspnet.  The RC1 changeset is at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/21528

Comment: But what does that mean?  Will it be implemented in the future?  Is it just an idea that might possibly come back in the future?  Is it safe/advisable to add it into my local source code?

Comment: Sorry.  I don't have any particular insight into the MVC teams plans.

Answer (score 1):

For others, this is a quick mockup of a SubmitButton extension for the HtmlHelper.

```
public static class HtmlLinkExtensions
{
    public static string SubmitButton(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string imageLink, string value, string altText)
    {
        return string.Format("<input type='image' src='{0}' value='{1}' alt='{2}' />", imageLink, value, altText);
    }
}
```